# ImportError: No module named data_io

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

l'm under python2.7 l can't import data_io l got this error :

```
ImportError: No module named data_io
```

Here is my code

```
import data_io
reload(data_io)
data = data_io.read_as_df(basename)
```

Comment: Do you write the module name correctly? Where is a documentation of the module?

Answer (score 0):

Have you run the command?

```
 pip install dataIO
```

If so are you sure it is install in the right directory? Please provide more details on your pathenv.